# Wordpress files

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create my site.
In this site you can create a post for someone who is your friend in site.
I want that the post which I had created should be manageable to me as well as to a friend for whom I had created that post.
Will anyone suggest me how to give permission to my friend to manage it as well?
Thanks in advance, any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your friend's role in user section,in your friend's profile.

Comment: thanxs for your reply, will you please provide me step as i am new in WordPress.

Comment: in wp-admin section->Users->add user(as your friend's detail) and at last there is a field called 'Role'and more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities